# Cannot save byte literals to csv file with Python

Tags: python-3.x, csv, encryption

I am trying to write a program that encrypts text data input by the user and saves the encrypted information to a csv file. To use the stream cipher I am first converting the string type data to bytes literals, then trying to save it in this format. The problem comes as I re-read the csv file the next time I open the program, the data I saved as bytes type has been converted to string type, including the `b''`. Please refer to the code below.

```
IN:
from Crypto.Cipher import Salsa20
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['secret info', 'more secret info'], 'col2': ['top secret stuff', 'hide from prying eyes']})

key = b'*Thirty-two byte (256 bits) key*'
nonce = b'*8 byte*'
cipher = Salsa20.new(key=key, nonce=nonce)

for col in df.columns:
    df[col] = df[col].apply(lambda a: a.encode('utf-8'))
    df[col] = df[col].apply(lambda a: cipher.encrypt(a))

print(f"Format of data in dataframe pre saving: {type(df.iloc[0, 0])}")
df.to_csv('my_data.csv', encoding='utf-8')

encrypted_df = pd.read_csv('my_data.csv', encoding='utf-8', index_col=0)
print(f"Format of data in re-read dataframe: {type(encrypted_df.iloc[0, 0])}")
```

```
OUT:
Format of data in dataframe pre saving: <class 'bytes'>
Format of data in re-read dataframe: <class 'str'>
```

Is there a way to read the csv file so that the data is of bytes type and not a string so that I can easily decrypt it?

I have tried:

1. Decoding the data back to strings prior to writing to the csv file, however this gives rise to a unicode decode error `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x9c in position 0: invalid start byte`
2. Stripping the `b''` from the strings and then encoding to bytes type, however the encoder does string escape adding loads backslashes so I then can't decrypt the text.

I'm relatively new to coding and very new to encryption so simple answers would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have found, CSV format can only deal with strings.  A common way to convert bytes to a string is Base64.  Change your bytes into a Base64 string which you can put into your CSV file.

When you read the CSV file you will get your Base64 back,  You then need to convert the Base64 back into the original bytes.

Comment: Wow this worked perfectly. It's easy when you know how! I wasted like 6 hours trying to figure this out ha. Thank you so much for your help

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but it is polite to accept a correct answer.  That helps other searching for the same answer later.